# How to use rails plus paperclip and fog in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, fog

I'm trying to setup my development environment to store and fetch images in local host.
I've manage to save the images on the correct path, but I can't find a way to load the page and retrieve them from the assets pipeline.

I have this on my model:

```
has_attached_file :cover, :styles => {:small => '80x80'},
                                    :storage => :fog,
                                    :fog_credentials => {:provider => "Local",
                                                         :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public"},
                                    :fog_directory => 'system/migos',
                                    :fog_host => "http://localhost:3000/assets",
                                    :default_url => '/assets/missing/:attachment/missing_:class_:style.png',
                                    :path => ':rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

and the file gets saved correctly to: 
**public/system/migos/development/workgroups/covers/000/000/011/small/logo.png**

When loading the page, it tries to fetch the file from here: 
**/assets/localhost/development/workgroups/covers/000/000/011/small/logo.png?1346598225**
and fails.

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you show me the code that you use to retrive the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 has_attached_file :photo,
   :url  => "/assets/vehicles/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
   :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/vehicles/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Try the code from above, check the URL and PATH, it will return the next image address:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/vehicles/1/original/72854906.jpg?1346092386
```

the folder structure is assets/vehicles/1/original.

Comment: Well, something like that does it, but I was trying, maybe wrongly, to use Fog for localhost as well.  In here https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults there seems to be an example, but it also fails when the page tries to load the images.

Comment: yes, also I think it's not good to use explicitly localhost:3000 as fog host, for development environment maybe it will work but not necessarily on TQA or Production environment, for example in my case I make the deployment to Tomcat servers under port 80. I think you can replace it (http://localhost:3000/) with the simbol :rails_root.

Comment: Fog Local does now work with Paperclip and `fog_host` can be empty (`''`) which will do a relative lookup. However setting a fog_directory seems to be ignored when constructing the URL. If I find a solution I'll post an answer.